# Is this conjecture regarding simple graphs obvious?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple directed graph such that no node is a sink node i.e. each node has at least one outgoing edge. Let the minimum outgoing edges for any node ($O_{min} = K; K>0$).

We can always remove the directed edges from the Graph such that:

1. Each Node loses 1 incoming and one outgoing edge.
2. For a node with 0 incoming edges it loses 1 exactly 1 outgoing edge.

Comment: In $A\to B \to C\to D\to B$, how can you remove edges so that $A$ loses one edge and each of $B,C,D$ loses two edges?

Comment: thank you.. yup its false.. is the generalization of this i.e. "Each Node loses exactly one outgoing edge (without caring about incoming edges)" also false..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the question answered I note that if for each node $v$ we remove an arbitrary edge $e_v$ outgoing from $v$ then each node will lose exactly one outgoing edge.